# python convert list to matrix and get value

Tags: python, list, matrix, nested, nested-lists

I'm quite new to python. I have a list of 16 1s and 0s in a nested list.

```
list([name_of_matrix],[1234567812345678], [another_name],[1234....])
```

Each of the number item `[12345678....]`in the list representing a 4x4 matrix like this:

```
1234
5678
1234
5678
```

My goal is to get access to a number by `[row, col].` For example [2,3] would be row 2, col3, which is 7. How should I convert the list to achieve this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. If an inner `list` represents a 4x4 matrix, does that mean the overall structure is meant to be 4x4x4?

Comment: @gmds it's a list of 4x4 matrix and their names, each of them is a 4 x4 as the example. does this explain it a bit better? I edited the question as well

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So each odd element is a string representing the name of the element immediately following it, which is a `list` containing a 16-digit integer that represents a 4x4 matrix?

Comment: @gmds exactly. I am struggling to come up with a loop that could convert and also access the value using [row, col]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should decompose your nested `list` into a `dict` where the keys are the strings representing names and the values are the integers:

```
nested_list = [['first'], [1234567812345678], ['second'], [1234432109877890]]
raw_dict = {k[0]: v[0] for k, v in zip(nested_list[::2], nested_list[1::2])}
```

Now, we want to turn each 16-digit integer into something that can better represent a matrix. `numpy` is one way, but let's stick to basic Python for now.

Observe that if we convert each integer into a string, each 4-character chunk will represent a row of the matrix. Accordingly:

```
def to_matrix(i):
    string = str(i)
    return [[int(element) for element in string[i:i + 4]] for i in range(0, 16, 4)]

matrix_dict = {k: to_matrix(v) for k, v in raw_dict.items()}
```

Now, our `dict` has for values nested `lists` which represent matrices:

```
print(matrix_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'first': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], 'second': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1], [0, 9, 8, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]}
```

We can access an arbitrary element by chained indexing:

```
print(matrix_dict['first'][3][2])
```

Output:

```
7
```

**EDIT**: In the case where we don't want to differentiate between lists, then we can just do this:

```
matrices = [to_matrix(element[0]) for element in nested_list if isinstance(element[0], int)]
```

Comment: Thanks! is there a way not using the dictionary? say if the original list structure has a new item, eg nested_list = [['first'], [nameOne],[1234567812345678], ['second'], [nameTwo],[1234432109877890]]

Comment: You could extract only those `lists` whose elements are integers, then call `to_matrix` on them as normal. How would you differentiate one inner `list` from another, though?

Comment: yes i only need to extract lists whose elements are integers. yea it's a good point  about differentiating inner list, at this point it's not so important for processing. but if there are 3 items, it's hard to make them fit in a dictionary right?

Comment: @user4046073 that would depend on where you got your data from. I have edited my answer to handle the second case that you have raised.

Comment: thanks so much, could you explain a bit more about the method, what is element[0] that I should pass?

Comment: because somehow I get an empty matrices with the code

Comment: @user4046073 Well, `nested_list` is a `list` of `lists`, where each `list` contains one element, an `int`, right? If you look at `to_matrix`, it assumes that the input is an `int`. Therefore, when iterating through the nested `list`, you need to refer to the first element (`[0]`) of *each* sub-`list`, to ensure that you actually get the value you want.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to pass the list as a string to the list method and create a numpy array with float types from that list:

```
my_matrix = np.array(list('1234567812345678'),dtype=float).reshape((4,4))
```

Now you can access it like:

```
my_matrix[2,3] #output 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary:

```
my_matrix_collection = {
    'name_one' : np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]),
    'name_two' : np.array([[10,20,30,40],[50,60,70,80],[10,20,30,40],[50,60,70,80]])
}
```

Now you can access the matrix elements of a specific matrix with, for example:

```
my_matrix_collection['name_one'][2,3] #output 4
```

To get the dictionary `my_matrix_collection` from your list (let's call it `my_list`), do:

```
my_matrix_collection = {} #create an empty dictionary
for i in range(len(my_list)//2):
    my_matrix_collection[my_list[2*i]] = np.array(list(my_list[2*i+1]),dtype=float)).reshape((4,4)) #populate the empty dictionary
```

Comment: the problem is I have an existing list in given format, and the digits are all in one line..